# Font Awesome Icons Do Not Display in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am working with Wordpress 3.5 and have tried both BootstrapCDN and Default CSS setup options as outlined in the Get Started http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/ page of Font Awesome. After I upload both the Font Awesome Icons and Wordpress Twitter Bootstrap CSS plugin, then insert the two lines of code into the  of my site, I attempt the basic icon insertion as follows in a project text box:

```
<i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> icon-camera-retro
```

The two lines of code inserted into the  are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

The icon simply doesn't display, while the text does and seems to be offset by a blank space where the icon should be. I'm relatively new to this, so I apologize if this is simplistic. If there are further instructions beyond those explained on the Get Started page which are very straight-forward (but do not seem to work for me), I would be grateful for that info. I appreciate any help you can afford. Thanks!

Comment: I should clarify, I've changed the href paths noted above to the appropriate strings.

Comment: What happens when you inspect that blank space in an HTML inspector (Chrome's "Inspect Element")?

Comment: The html reads as it's written and the pop-up on the page shows: i.icon-camera-retro 14px x 14px

Comment: @dnord, is there something specific I should be looking for in the HTML? Thanks for the help, by the way.

Comment: Does it work on other browser?

Comment: Did you get this worked out?

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered a simmilar problem - but only in case of Chrome (in other browsers it worked fine). I tried to remove scripts - one by one, to identify, which one is responsible for that. In my case, it was (otherwise very cool plugin) fitVids.js